# ORACLE trigger instead of insert on view with a nested table

Tags: oracle, view, triggers

I have to write a trigger. It compiles everything, but if I want to insert something in my view, i get an error message. Maybe you can help me.

```
SET DEFINE off;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER LieferantOV_trig

INSTEAD OF INSERT
ON LIEFERANT_OV
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  IF INSERTING THEN
  INSERT INTO Lieferant (LiefNr, Name, Adresse)  
  VALUES(:new.LiefNr, :new.Name, ntTAdresse());

  INSERT INTO TABLE (SELECT Adresse FROM Lieferant  ) VALUES
  (TAdresse(:new.Straße, :new.PLZ, :new.Ort));

  END IF;
  END;

INSERT INTO Lieferant_OV 
VALUES(752443, 'Laepple Teublitz', 'Maxstr. 12', '93158', 'Teublitz');
```

For the nested Table

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TAdresse AS OBJECT(
Straße VARCHAR2(50),
PLZ VARCHAR2(5),
Ort VARCHAR2(50)
);



CREATE TABLE Lieferant(
LiefNr number(6) PRIMARY KEY,
Name varchar2(20) NOT NULL
);
1.
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ntTAdresse AS TABLE OF TAdresse;
2.
ALTER TABLE Lieferant ADD Adresse ntTAdresse NESTED TABLE Adresse STORE AS TAdresseNT;


CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Lieferant_OV (LiefNr, Name, Straße, PLZ, ORT) 
AS SELECT k.LiefNr, k.Name, l.Straße, l.PLZ, l.Ort 
FROM Lieferant k, table(k.Adresse) l;
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Hey, i added a bit more code. Got this error:                                           SQL-ERROR: ORA-04098: Trigger 'S74040.LIEFERANT_OV_TRIG' ist ungültig und konnte nicht neu bestätigt werden
04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"

Comment: Do you want to insert one single row?

Comment: Yes sir. If I insert it without the trigger, it works.

Comment: what if you already had row with 752443 LeifNr? you want to update the row?

Comment: My table is nearly clear. There is just one row. It doesnt matter, i dont need a update comment now.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax should be like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER LieferantOV_trig
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
   ON LIEFERANT_OV
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
   INSERT INTO Lieferant (LiefNr, Name, Adresse)  
   VALUES(:new.LiefNr, :new.Name, ntTAdresse(TAdresse(:new.Straße,:new.PLZ,:new.ORT));

END;
```

You can skip `IF INSERTING THEN` because your trigger fires only on `INSERT`

Note, by this each record have at maximum only one address, thus a nested table does not make much sense.

In order to add an address to existing Lieferant you can do this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER LieferantOV_trig
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
   ON LIEFERANT_OV
   FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
   lieferantCount INTEGER;
BEGIN 

   select count(*) 
   into lieferantCount 
   from Lieferant 
   where LiefNr = :new.LiefNr
       and Name = :new.Name;

   if lieferantCount = 0 then
      INSERT INTO Lieferant (LiefNr, Name, Adresse)  
      VALUES(:new.LiefNr, :new.Name, ntTAdresse(TAdresse(:new.Straße,:new.PLZ,:new.ORT)));
   else
      UPDATE Lieferant 
      SET Adresse = Adresse MULTISET UNION ntTAdresse(TAdresse(:new.Straße,:new.PLZ,:new.ORT))
      WHERE LiefNr = :new.LiefNr
         and Name = :new.Name;
   end if;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want do this if you want to keep one row per insertion.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER LieferantOV_trig

INSTEAD OF INSERT
ON LIEFERANT_OV
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Lieferant (LiefNr, Name, Adresse)  
  VALUES(:new.LiefNr, :new.Name, ntTAdresse(TAdresse(:new.Straße, :new.PLZ, :new.Ort)));
END;
/
```

This works if the Adresse column contain only one Adress. But that is not purpose of a nested table. So you probably want to check if there is an existing row in the table with given LiefNr. If yes, only insert into the nested table.

Comment: Okay thanks. No this trigger compiles with no errors as well in this form. I had this nearly the same. But I get an error as well if I insert a row in my view like this: INSERT INTO Lieferant_OV 
VALUES(752443, 'Laepple Teublitz', 'Maxstr. 12', '93158', 'Teublitz');